# How to remove script initialisation from javaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this [grid](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/), however I do not wish to use the Masonry plugin, so the article states I need to remove the initialisation, however I do not know how to do this.

The function is as follows...

```
_init : function() {
        this.items = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.el.id + ' > div' ) );
        this.itemsCount = this.items.length;
        this.itemsRenderedCount = 0;
        this.didScroll = false;

        var self = this;

        imagesLoaded( this.el, function() {

            // initialize masonry
            new Masonry( self.el, {
                itemSelector: 'div',
                transitionDuration : 0
            } );

            if( Modernizr.cssanimations ) {
                // the items already shown...
                self.items.forEach( function( el, i ) {
                    if( inViewport( el ) ) {
                        self._checkTotalRendered();
                        classie.add( el, 'shown' );
                    }
                } );

                // animate on scroll the items inside the viewport
                window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
                    self._onScrollFn();
                }, false );
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {
                    self._resizeHandler();
                }, false );
            }

        });
    },
```

How can I successfully remove the initialisation of the masonry script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing the lines

```
// initialize masonry
new Masonry( self.el, {
    itemSelector: 'div',
    transitionDuration : 0
});
```

[edit] After removing the lines above and you need to make the following changes to your HTML:

```
<script src="js/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> -->
```

Simply download and include `EventEmitter.min.js` from https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter.

Comment: Yes I tried that, however when I also remove the actual masonry script file from being called in the page, it throws an error, so wanted to check if there was anything else

Comment: @Adam "it throws an error" << might want to share that error. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it does not throw an error, the script just does not run. It seems to rely on this file masonry.pkgd.min.js - https://github.com/codrops/GridLoadingEffects/tree/master/js

Comment: @Adam ic. Well, according to the article you still need to `adjust the selectors etc.`. So you need to get your hands dirty and do something with `self.el` like creating the elements you need, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately that is beyond my knowledge in javaScript.

Comment: @Adam Updated my answer with a solution to your problem (just tested it locally). Altough I don't think you want to remove masonry…

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however that script is a little buggy. It works first time in production, but then when you refresh, i get an error. Thanks for your help anyway, I will make correct answer as you answered the original question

Comment: @Adam Well, `EventEmitter` is used (among some other libraries) by `Masonry` itself. But you're right, that should be a new question. ;-)